# Should all intermediate tensor in custom layer be registered as "non-trainable-weight"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, out-of-memory

I'm writing custom layers with `Keras`. But "non-trainable-weight" confused me. Let's say I have a simple layer as follows (It only do one thing, divided average by std):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
K = tf.keras.backend
class SharpeLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SharpeLayer, self).__init__()
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        return K.mean(inputs) / (K.std(inputs) + K.epsilon()) * 15.87450787
```

There as two intermediate tensor: `mean` and `std`. Should I register these two tensor as `non-trainable-weight`?

**My thinking about this:** I know it will not affect final training results. My goal here is to estimate the **memory consumption** of my model. I not sure if the intermediate tensor will also cost GPU memory. If so, I think all intermediate tensor should be registered as `non-trainable-weight`, so that `model.summary` could reflect the real memory cost.

Answer (score 0):

You should register only instance variables of the Layer class. Intermediate tensors are created by tensorflow and you should not care about them.

Registering tensors as trainable/non-trainable doesn't change their memory consumption. It determines whether to update these tensors in the process of backpropagation of gradients.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I understand whether the registration won't affact the memory consumption. My question is: do you think the intermediate tensor would cost GPU memory or not? In this case, the `K.mean` and `K.std`?